# Logarithmic limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms

This has been described as another "way" to do "logarithmic" limits.

a. Given that $a^n=e^{n \ln a}$ prove that if  $0<a<1$, then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a^n = 0$

This intuitively makes sense but I do not know how to formally prove this after making the substitution $\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{n \ln a}$

b. We are asked to calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2+n}$ using what we have shown in part (a). I know how to do this by setting $y=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{n^2+n}$ and taking the logarithm of both sides but we are supposed to do it with this "new" method from part (a).
All suggestions and comments welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Hint for a:

Recall that $n \ln a = \ln a^n$. So $e^{n \ln a} = e^{\ln a^n}$. Now, what do you know about the definition of a logarithm? What cancels immediately?

Answer (score 2):

Well, $0<a<1$ implies $\ln(a) < 0$, so $\ln(a) = -|\ln(a)|$.  Then $\mathrm{e}^{n \ln(a)} = \mathrm{e}^{- |\ln(a)| n}$ and the limit should be very easy to see (since $|\ln(a)|$ is just some constant).

Note that for $n$ sufficiently large, $n^2 < n^2+n < n^2+n^2 = 2 n^2$ and then $\mathrm{e}^{2 \ln(n)/n} = n^{2/n} = \sqrt[n]{n^2} < \sqrt[n]{n^2+n} < \sqrt[n]{2n^2} = (2n)^{2/n} = \mathrm{e}^{2 \ln(2n)/n}$ and the rest should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a^n = e^x$

Taking log both the sides, you get $x = n.log(a)/log(e)$ = $n \ln a$

Part 2. If $0<a<1$ then $\ln a< 0 $ (log of number less than 1 is negative)

so we can conviniently write 1. $$a^n =( \frac{1}{e^{|\ln a|}})^n$$

so denominator in this is positive, and anything over a positive number raised to the power limiting to infinity, tends to be 0.

Part 3.

Use the result $$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } \left( 1+{\frac {x}{n}} \right) ^{n} = {{\rm e}^{x}}$$

Take out $n^2$ common, nth root means power is 1/n

Comment: Sorry your part 3 explanation is a little confusing. Could you please further explain how you set up that particular limit?